# how to print pretty json string for data in swift

Tags: swift

I would like to log payload into a pretty print format however, based on my following code. I still see `\"`. how can I make the output like pretty json string format?

```
"{
    "string1":"string1",
    "string2":"string2",
    "val":42
    }"
```

```
extension Encodable {
    /// format the json data to string
    var jsonString: String? {
        let encoder = JSONEncoder()
        encoder.dateEncodingStrategy = .iso8601
        encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
        let jsonString = try! encoder.encode(self)
        return String(decoding: jsonString, as: UTF8.self)
    }
}
struct Foo: Codable {
    let string1: String
    let string2: String
    let val: Int
}
let foo = Foo(string1: "string1", string2: "string2", val: 42)
print(foo.jsonString)
//

// "{\"string1\":\"string1\",\"string2\":\"string2\",\"val\":42}"
```

Comment: The backslash is only shown in `print` statements. The backslashes are not actually in the string.

Comment: But that's how I see it from log and from time to time we need to copy and paste those payload from log.bsupper annoying to remove all backslash

Comment: I know I've been able to achieve this in the past, but recently I've just copied into sublime text and used a find/replace option.  Can't remember if its a limitation or something I do out of habit now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see `\"` because you are printing an `Optional`. When printing `Optional`, it shows you the string literal held by this optional container, which will be quoted in `"`, so the content is escaped as well, like when you write it in code.

```
Optional("{\n  \"string2\" : \"string2\",\n  \"val\" : 42,\n  \"string1\" : \"string1\"\n}")
```

If you replace the print statement with

```swift
print(foo.jsonString ?? "")
```

You will see the string content:

```json
{
  "string2" : "string2",
  "string1" : "string1",
  "val" : 42
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The confusion happens because you specified the wrong return type.

As you clearly return a non-optional string remove the question mark in the declaration line

```
var jsonString: String {
```

---

You get the same by force unwrapping `jsonString` in the `print` line

```
print(foo.jsonString!)
```

but changing the return type is the better choice.